# Creating custom markers with Leaflet.js add multiple markers on the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm writing an app and i'm trying to add custom markers using Leaflet.js .The code so far worked, and add custom markers to the map successfully, however the default markers exist too on the map.

```
   var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-1.3938636,36.7442377], 13);
   var mapdata =  $.ajax({
        url: '/data.json',
        dataType: 'text',
         success: function(data) {
            var geojson;
            geojson = $.parseJSON(data);



                L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
                    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    id: 'mapbox.streets',
                    accessToken: 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
                }).addTo(mymap);

                //add external geojson to map
            var cordinates = L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(mymap);

             //Add popups to markers
            function onEachFeature(feature,layer){
               if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
                }
            }
            L.geoJSON(geojson, { onEachFeature: onEachFeature }).addTo(mymap);


                //Adding custom markers to maps
                var HospIcon = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: '<%= asset_path('red_MarkerH.png') %>',

                    iconSize:     [20, 50], // size of the icon
                    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
                    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to markers location
                    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
                    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                });

                var Custom_marker = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
                   pointToLayer : function(feature,latlng){
                      return L.marker(latlng, {icon: HospIcon}).addTo(mymap);
                   }
                });
        }


    });


    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

How can i solve this.Any help will be highly appreciated.[This is what the maps look like,The blue markers are the default,the red markers are the custom markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqgQj.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this function

```
var cordinates = L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(mymap);
```

will add your coordinates and use default markers icon, if you want to modify the default marker, you should define callback in that function as below

```
my_json = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
            iconSize: [27, 27],
            iconAnchor: [13, 27],
            popupAnchor: [1, -24],
            iconUrl: 'icone/chapel-2.png'
        });
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
    }
});
```

in your case, marker drawn twice because you render it twice `addTo(mymap)`, from the first you inject GeoJson. And second, when you define your icons and add it to your map

references :

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121424/leaflet-how-to-use-a-custom-marker-on-a-geojson-layer
- http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/61fa02b35abf4b971390